# Androids WifiManager returns -1 on adding a new connection

Tags: java, android, wifimanager

I am writing an app to add a secure wifi enterprise configuration on android. The problem is this app is working as intended on my Samsung galaxy S4 mini but on the second phone a LG L40 it returns allways -1 when i add the connection. The permissions are set.

Here are some code parts:

```
wifiManager = (WifiManager)appContext.getSystemService("wifi");
returnValue = wifiManager.addNetwork(wifiConfig);
```

The SSID is quotet in the wifiConfig. I think it is a device specific problem. Is there a way to get the RemoteException in the WifiManager?

Comment: Please, show your code that we can help you.

Comment: +1 show your code, and as documentation, -1 means fail, so a reason of fail could be that the wifi is already added? check this point... and as alexey mentioned, post some code

Comment: I' ve checked it, there is no wifi configured at the LG Device. On the Samsung device it is working. On both devices is Android 4.4.2.